# CakePHP month names translations

Tags: cakephp, date, translation

What is the best way to translate months names into another language when I use

```
$form->input('date_field');
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The month names are already wrapped in `__()` so you can just provide the translations (as per http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Common-Tasks-With-CakePHP/Internationalization-Localization.html) and it should work.